# Flutter_background_service doest work IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Why does the background service not work on iOS devices? I gave all the necessary permissions and tried every way. flutter_background_service: I'm using ^0.0.1+21 and it says IOS support.

I'm trying to add a pedometer. It works perfectly in the background on Android, but I could not run it on IOS even though I met all the conditions.

When I close the application, it continues to work on android. How can I make this possible on iOS?

Comment: Perhaps [edit] your question to show what you are trying and what you expect to happen. Apps on iOS cannot execute arbitrary or kin the background indefinitely. This plug-in schedules a background task to run every 15 minutes but ios does not guarantee that the task will run on that schedule. It considers power state, how much work your app does in the background and other factors when deciding to schedule background work.

Comment: I'm trying to add a pedometer. It works perfectly in the background on Android, but I could not run it on IOS even though I met all the conditions.
When I close the application, it continues to work on android. How can I make this possible on iOS?

Comment: You don't need any background processing for a pedometer on iOS.  You simply use [`CMPedometer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer) and updates will be delivered when you call [`startUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer/1613950-startupdates) - When your app moves to the background, updates are paused, but the system continues counting steps.  When your app returns to the foreground the deferred step count updates will be delivered.

Comment: Do you have a resource on how to do this in flutter?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pedometer ?

Comment: I did some extra work to calculate my daily step because it didn't work as expected on Android. I understand that these are not needed for IOS, from what you said. I think it's enough to use this package directly. Because as you said android and ios working logic is different.